# Can't scroll when using git blame/log/show

Tags: git, vim

I recently started experiencing an unusual issue with vim on my work machine. If I do a git blame/log/show, I can no longer scroll through the results with my arrows keys. I can still use any other vim command (search, scroll to bottom, scroll x pages, etc.). There is also this --MORE-- message that is now being shown at the bottom of the screen which I think might have something to do with it. I have tried resetting my .vimrc and this did not resolve the issue. I have attached a screenshot of the issue.[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's `more` you're looking at, not `vim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `git` detects that its output will be long, it sends it through a pager. Typically, this will be `less`, but it looks like in your case the inferior `more` is being used.

You can set your preferred pager via the `PAGER` environment variable. Try `echo $PAGER` to see what it's set to, and add `export PAGER=less` (or just `export PAGER=`) to your shell startup file to make the change. (Don't set it to `vim`; `vim` is an editor, not a pager, and you cannot pipe stuff into it.)